# AttributeError, why?

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that solves a tetravex and I encountered this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'PlacementList'.
```

I tried everything I know but don't know why I'm getting that error. Could you please tell me what I did wrong?

This is a pastebin link to my code: http://pastebin.com/d1WdbCUu

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please paste your code here, not on some other website. http://stackoverflow.com/ is here to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers; what happens when your code host shuts their doors or expires old posts? This would become (more) useless and of no help to others in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Why post a pastebin link when SO can handle code appropriately?

Comment: You need to post a usable link to some code if you want any help.

Answer (score 2):

It happens when you are trying to get `PlacementList` attribute of a list, obviously.

Here is the example:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.PlacementList
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#49>", line 1, in <module>
    a.PlacementList
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'PlacementList'
```

Just find the code where something similar happens - you are trying to get `PlacementList` attribute of the object that can be of type `list`.

Comment: It goes through it the first time and doesn't display any error. I used print statements to figure to come to this conclusion. If u look at my code, I have print statements in some functions. This display is:

Comment: @k.ken: Which line exactly caused the error? You may be passing list in many functions that try to access `PlacementList` attribute, but I will not execute this script if you already have the data (the line number especially).

Comment: line 227 in my isGoal function. PlacementList is a slot in my class and I created the class instance in my main: Config = config() and then passed the instance(Config) to all my functions. *Check main function*

Comment: I traced it now and know how the problem occurs. my solve function calls my successors function which returns a list and then that list is recursive passed to my solve function(line 219) which then passes it to my isGoal function and then it returns the error. How do I fix this?

Comment: @k.ken: Then the problem probably lies in `successors()` function - it should never return list of lists, only list of objects of `config` class.

Comment: @k.ken: Oh, so you found it yourself. I do not have single & short tip on how to fix this, I do not even know the purpose of your script. But you can surely fix this by forcing `successors()` function to return only empty list or list of `config` class objects. Good luck.

Comment: I changed it but that didn't work lol. It's back to it's original form. My successors function is a function that takes a valid conguration and returns a list
of valid configurations.

Comment: @k.ken: The problem lies in your `successors()` function or you did not show us the whole code. There is no other way to reach this error, because `isGoal()` is called only in `solve()` (on `solve()`'s only parameter). `solve()` is called in two places, one of which is where it is called on empty `config()` instance. The second place is when it is called in loop, on each iteration over the result of `successors()`. And there is the problem. Do you believe me? Change it to return only list of `config` instances, it will work. And really try to simplify your code, plus follow PEP8.

Comment: What's PEP8? Could you please give an example of what you mean by list of config? I don't understand what it means

Comment: @k.ken: PEP8 is a [style guide for Python code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), and by "_list of `config` instances_" I meant the list (`[]`), where **every single element** (if there is any) is an instance of `config` class. One of the examples of such list is `[config(), config(), config()]`.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand what you mean. I have to think of how to do this for a while.

Comment: I tried using recursion to get the list of configurations as stated above but it keeps returning None. This is the error message:'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @k.ken: If you paste `con = []; type(con.append('sth'))` into your IDLE window, you will see that the result is: `<type 'NoneType'>`. Which means that eg. your `return Con.append(successors(Config))` code works as `Con.append(successors(Config)); return None`. Do you see now, where is the problem?

Comment: Could not appending before returning be the problem? If that is so, I need to append first before I return the variable.

Comment: @k.ken: I do not know what you want to achieve, but invoking `Con.append(successors(Config))` first and then returning `Con` (by `return Con`) should help you get rid of the problem. Just check it.

Comment: I tried doing it that way but it didn't. Here is a link to my code: http://pastebin.com/GUXBd9fA

Comment: @k.ken: I do not know what your code does and do not want to get into much detail, but try also `return successors(Config)` or `return Con + successors(Config)`, some of these options may work. Anyway, I am not here to write the whole code for you and fix all the bugs, but to answer your question :) The question has been answered and I believe the code no longer throws this error. At least you know the source of the error and how to fix it.